# navigation not working in sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

Hi i am new to sencha and i am trying on navigation here i am clicking on one button in VehicleSubPage1 then it navigate to AccountInfo but it is not working,
here code i am writing

can any one help me

**VehicleSubPage1 class **

```
Ext.define("myproject.view.VehicleSubPage1", {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
        xtype:'VehicleSubPage1form',
        requires: [
        'myproject.view.AccountInfo'
        ],

    config: {

                title: 'Account Info',
                iconCls: 'home',
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Push another view!',
                    handler: function() {
                      view.push({

                         xtype:'AccountInfoform'

                     });
                    }
                }
            ]        
    }

});
```

**AccountInfo class**

```
Ext.define("myproject.view.AccountInfo", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        xtype:'AccountInfoform',
    config: {

               url: 'contact.php',
                title: 'Account Info',
                iconCls: 'home',
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,
                items:[
                 {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'send',
                ui: 'confirm',
                handler:function(){
                alert("clicked");
                }

                } 
                ]   

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that `view` in the button handler is undefined. What you actually want to do is to call the `push` method of the navigation view. So add an id attribute to your `VehicleSubPage1` and change the handler into the following:

```
function() {
    var accountInfo = Ext.getCmp('accountInfo'); //assuming you have set the id of VehicleSubPage1 as id: 'accountInfo'
    accountInfo.push({
        xtype:'AccountInfoform'
    });
}
```